# use SUM on certain conditions

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a script that extracts transactions and their details from a database. But my users complain that the file size being generated is too large, and so they asked for certain transactions to be just summed up/consolidated instead if they are of a certain classification, say Checking Accounts. That means there should only be one line in the result set named "Checking" which contains the sum of all transactions under Checking Accounts. Is there a way for an SQL script to go like:

```
CASE 
    WHEN Acct_class = 'Checking'
        then sum(tran_amount)
    ELSE tran_amount
END
```

I already have the proper `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY` statements, but I can't seem to get my desired output. There is still more than one "Checking" line in the result set. Any ideas would be very much appreciated.

Comment: A column can't be argument to aggregate function just sometimes. (Either always, or never.) Can you give us some sample table data and the expected result?

Answer (score 0):

Try This,

```
   Select sum(tran_amount) From tran_amount Where Acct_class = 'Checking'
```

Comment: I believe the OP needs to extract all rows ( aggregating or not), not only those of a certain class

Comment: yes, all rows, all details. However, for Checking accounts, I will hide all the details and just display the sum of the transactions.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to achieve this using [`UNION ALL`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp)

```
SELECT tran_amount, .... FROM table WHERE NOT Acct_class = 'Checking'
UNION ALL
SELECT SUM(tran_amount), .... FROM table WHERE Acct_class = 'Checking' GROUP BY Acct_class, ...;
```

Comment: tried this, script takes too much time to finish. :(

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like the following, by keeping single rows for some classes, and aggregating for some others:

```
with test (id, class, amount) as
(
select 1, 'a'       , 100 from dual union all
select 2, 'a'       , 100 from dual union all
select 3, 'Checking', 100 from dual union all
select 4, 'Checking', 100 from dual union all
select 5, 'c'       , 100 from dual union all
select 6, 'c'       , 100 from dual union all
select 7, 'c'       , 100 from dual union all
select 8, 'd'       , 100 from dual
)
select sum(amount), class
from test
group by case 
                when class = 'Checking' then null /* aggregates elements of class 'b' */
                else id /* keeps elements of other classes not aggregated */
         end,
         class
```

Answer (score 0):

hi you can try below sql

```
select account_class, 
case when account_class = 'saving' then listagg(trans_detail, ',')  within group (order by emp_name) -- will give you all details transactions 
                 when account_class = 'checking' then to_char(sum(trans_detail)) -- will give you only sum of transactions
                                             end  as trans_det from emp group by account_class;
```

Answer (score 0):

Or, if your desired output is getting either the sum, either the actual column value based on another column value, the solution would be to use an analytical function to get the sum together with the actual value:

```
select 
    decode(acct_class, 'Checking', tran_amount_sum, tran_amount) 
  from (
    select 
        sum(tran_amount) over (partition by acct_class) as tran_amount_sum, 
        tran_amount, 
        acct_class 
      from 
        YOUR_TABLE
  )
```